# Ruby On Rails has many through not saving / displaying views properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to get Order and Products linked together via a join table called orders_products, an order has many :products though :order_products and a product has many :orders though :order_products, however when I save the form and look in the view no products are displayed for that order.

---

**new.html.erb for Order**

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
<%= f.input :order_number %>

<%= hidden_field_tag "order[product][]", nil %>
<% Product.all.each do |product| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "order[product_ids][]", product.id, @order.product_ids.include?(product.id), id: dom_id(product) %>
  <%= label_tag dom_id(product), product.name %><br>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit %>
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :order_products, class_name: "OrderProduct"
  has_many :products, through: :order_products
end
```

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_products, class_name: "OrderProduct"
  has_many :orders, through: :order_products
end
```

**order_product.rb**

```
class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
end
```

**show.html.erb for Order**

```
<div class="well">
  <%= "Order number " + @order.order_number %>
  <% @order.products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.name %>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried `<%= simple_form_for [@order, Product.new] do |f| %>`?

Comment: Its okay its fixed now, because I forgot to add product ids to my strong parameters